# Constructor Dependency Injection using Spring framework, unable to retain the value

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

This is the XML file `bean-jojo.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


        <bean id="vTypeCar" class="com.justPractise.ex01.Car" />
        <bean id="vTypeBike" class="com.justPractise.ex01.MotorCycle" />        

        <bean id="vService" class="com.justPractise.ex01.VehicalService">
            <property name="vehical" ref="vTypeBike" />
        </bean>     

        <bean id="beanLifeCycleTest" class="com.jal.LifeCycleBeanP2">
            <property name="justAParam" value="MICHEAL JACKSON" />
        </bean>     

        <bean id="brun-p" class="com.justPractise.ex01.HALBrunPojo">
            <constructor-arg value="234" />
        </bean>                 
</beans>
```

I've registered on the following bean, on which I am trying constructor DI:

```java
package com.justPractise.ex01;

public class HALBrunPojo {

    private Integer num;

    public HALBrunPojo(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" INITIALISED ");
    }

    public HALBrunPojo(int num){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" PARAMETERISED..... INITIALISED "+num);
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(Integer num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}
```

As seen in the XML for the above bean declaration, I have specified the constructor-arg,
now this is the following code used which has the main method:

```java
package com.justPractise.ex01;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainPractise01 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = null;      
        HALBrunPojo obj = null;
        try{
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean-jojo.xml");
            obj = (HALBrunPojo) ctx.getBean("brun-p");
            System.out.println(" PARAM-VALUE "+(obj == null ? "0" : obj.getNum()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to run the above class from the command line, the output is

```
PARAM-VALUE 0
```

That means `HALBrunPojo` is `null`. After debugging I found out that if I commented the bean declaration of `LifeCycleBeanP2` in `bean-jojo.xml`, like this:

```xml
        <!--
        <bean id="beanLifeCycleTest" class="com.jal.LifeCycleBeanP2">
            <property name="justAParam" value="MICHEAL JACKSON" />
        </bean>     
        -->
```

and then I run the program, I get desired output, i.e

```
PARAM-VALUE 234
```

Why so?, this is the code of the bean `LifeCycleBeanP2.java`:

```java
package com.jal;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class LifeCycleBeanP2 implements BeanNameAware, BeanFactoryAware, BeanPostProcessor, InitializingBean, DisposableBean{
    String justAParam;

    public LifeCycleBeanP2(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" INITIALISED...... ");
    }

    public String getJustAParam() {
        return justAParam;
    }

    public void setJustAParam(String justAParam) {
        System.out.println(" SETTER OF JustAParam ........ ");
        this.justAParam = justAParam;
    }

    // method of BeanNameAware
    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String arg0) {
        System.out.println(" IN SET BEAN-NAME "+arg0);
    }

    // method of BeanFactoryAware
    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(" IN SET BEAN-FACTORY, "+arg0.getClass().getName());
    }

    // method of BeanPostProcessor
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(" POST PROCESS AFTER INITIALISATION ");
        return null;
    }

    // method of BeanPostProcessor
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(" POST PROCESS BEFORE INITIALISATION ");
        return null;
    }

    //method of InitializingBean
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" AFTER PROPERTIES SET ");
    }

    //method of DisposableBean
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" BEAN "+this.getClass().getName()+" QUALIFIED FOR GARBAGE COLLECTION ");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bean that implements a BeanPostProcessor interface is a special bean. It is passed a reference to all the other beans that are created by the context, **it can modify them and return a different instance if required**.

**Whatever reference returned by the BeanPostProcessor will then be associated with the bean id.**

In your LifeCycle class you are returning null - instead you should return the reference to the object that was passed to your methods. Change the two methods as follows, it should work as expected.

```
   // method of BeanPostProcessor
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(" POST PROCESS AFTER INITIALISATION ");
        return arg0;
    }

    // method of BeanPostProcessor
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(" POST PROCESS BEFORE INITIALISATION ");
        return arg0;
    }
```